# Overloading the ++ operator to increment an iterator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iterator, operators, operator-overloading

I am currently creating a square list and one of the requirements is to overload the the pre- and postfix ++ operator.

I've tried to overload the ++operator in my .hpp file to increment an iterator. But when calling the ++operator it does not call the overloaded code and just uses the default.

```
iterator& operator ++ () {  // pre-increment 
        std::list<int>::iterator i = list_Values.begin(); 
        advance(i,1); 
        return &*i; 
    } 

    iterator operator ++ (int) { // post-increment 
        std::list<int>::iterator i = list_Values.begin(); 
        advance(i,1); 
        return &*i; 
    }
```

I try to invoke the ++operator this way:

```
int* test = sqrList.begin();
  ++test;

  test++;
```

Comment: Default? There is no default `operator++`!

Comment: @Pubby well when i step through it goes inside the standard library

Comment: It would help if we could see your full class definition, especially if your type has base classes.

Comment: Why would you define ++ on a container? Do it on an iterator type, sure, but not the container...

Comment: It looks like `++` applied to *any* iterator always gives you one past the beginning, is that right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit are you talking about where i have the std:list<int>::itertator .... ?

Comment: @KerrekSB For some reason it doesn't even enter my overloaded method to incriement one past the beginning

Comment: Your code is faulty. *Very* faulty. You're returning a pointer to something when an iterator is expected as the return type, you're returning a reference to a local variable in the preincrement, and it seems you have `operator++` in the container class!

Comment: @Xeo i understand that the code is faulty but I couldnt even get the code to enter the overloaded method. I was just showing code to show I have put effort into this

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didnt know it was crappy..Its more just trying to get it to enter my operator first

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean no offense to anyone, I'm just trying to get it to enter my operator then i can figure out the inside code

Comment: @user1219627: I think you should revisit the design _first_. Also there is no "it": you haven't shown us any testcase that attemps to invoke this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* test = sqrList.begin();
++test;
test++;
```

You're incrementing a `int*`, and since there's no `int*` class to extend, you cannot possibly have *actually* created operators for this type.

Create the operators for the correct type, instead. You probably mean to make your own Iterator type.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the operator inside the class.

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator& operator ++ ()
    {
       return *this;
    }
    Iterator operator ++ (int)
    {
       return *this;
    }
};
```

Also, why are you using `return &*i;`?

Note that these operators need to be declared inside the `Iterator` class, not inside the container.

Comment: i've tried before and it still doesn't seem to enter my overloaded function

Comment: wasnt me who downvoted. Anyways I think this is what i need to do..I'll give it a try and comment

Answer (score 1):

For novices it is sometimes hard to understand an issue out of context. So I decided to provide a more or less complete example of defining custom iterator and overloading its operators.
Notice, when overloading  post increment operator, we return iterator by value, not by reference.
Of course, this is not a real world example, where we would not use raw pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
    node() :data(0), next(nullptr) {}
    node(int d) :data(d), next(nullptr) {}
};

//forward declaration
class MyList;

class MyListIterator
{
private:
    node* _ptr;
    friend class MyList;
    explicit MyListIterator(node* n) : _ptr(n) {}
public:
    int& operator*() const {
        return _ptr->data;
    }
    //overload pre increment operator
    MyListIterator& operator++() {
        _ptr = _ptr->next;
        return *this;
    }
    // overload post increment operator
    MyListIterator operator++(int) {
        MyListIterator ret = *this;
        ++* (this);
        return ret;
    }

    bool operator==(const MyListIterator& iter) const {
        return this->_ptr == iter._ptr;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MyListIterator& iter) const {
        return this->_ptr != iter._ptr;
    }
};

class MyList
{
private:
    node* _head;
    node* _tail;
    size_t _size;
public:
    MyList() : _head(nullptr), _tail(nullptr), _size(0) {};

    void push_back(int d) {
        node* newTail = new node(d);
        if (_tail != nullptr) {
            _tail->next = newTail;
        }
        else {
            _head = newTail;
        }
        _tail = newTail;
        _size++;
    }

    int& operator[](size_t i) {
        if (i >= _size)
            throw std::out_of_range("MyList");
        node * p = _head;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        return p->data;
    }

void remove(int d) {
    if (_head == nullptr)
        return;
    node * p = _head;
    node * prev = p;
    while ((p != nullptr) && (p->data != d)) {
        prev = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    if (p != nullptr) {
        if (p == _head)
            _head = p->next;
        else
            prev->next = p->next;
        delete p;
        _size--;
    }
}

    size_t size() const {
        return _size;
    }

    ~MyList() {
        node* next = nullptr;
        for (node* p = _head; p != nullptr; p = next) {
            next = p->next;
            delete p;
        }
    }
    using iterator = MyListIterator;
    iterator begin() { return iterator(_head); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(_tail->next); }
};

int main()
{

    MyList mylist;
    mylist.push_back(1);
    mylist.push_back(2);
    mylist.push_back(3);
    int count = 1;
    //pre increment
    for (MyListIterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
        assert(*it == count++);
    count = 1;
    //post increment
    for (MyListIterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it++)
        assert(*it == count++);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        assert(mylist[i] == i + 1);

    mylist.remove(2);
    assert(mylist[0] == 1);
    assert(mylist[1] == 3);
    assert(mylist.size() ==2);

    mylist.remove(1);
    mylist.remove(3);
    assert(mylist.size() == 0);

}
```